# Android Listview in alertDialog

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an activity with ListView populated by SQLite. you can see the ListView in an AlertDialog populated from db? is new to me!

how to insert the logic to get the data? for example the method getView!

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dettaglio>(this, R.layout.dettaglio_cate, R.id.tv_noe_cat, dettagli){


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


            TextView tvId, tvCaa;
            ImageView tvCe;

            tvCe = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.color_view);                               tvId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lbl);
            tvCaa = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_noria);


            Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);

            tvId.setText(d.id+"");
            tvCaa.setText(d.ca+"");
                  tvCe.setBackgroundColor(d.colore);

            return row;
        };
    };
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: And what is exactly problem you are facing?

Comment: are you asking or telling? :)

Comment: do you want to display a dialog on android list view row click?

Comment: exactly, which is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well normally i do this by passing an Array list to the Constructor of an Extended custom adapter and with each `getView` call the position is available from which i get the indexed object from the list and then tag that object to the View returned by the `getView` function.

Then whenever clicked the object can again be accessed.